# There's any way to know the percentage done of a non query?

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010, bulkinsert, executenonquery

There's any way to know the percentage of a non query?
I mean how much of the process is done, I have the process ID(Connection_ID)

I have an huge INSERT and I want to know from my VB.NET application how much is done.

I don't know if that possible.

Thanks.

Comment: You could attempt to use `PreparedStatements` and execute statements in batches, and from there progress a percentage internally

Comment: are you executing the query directly from vb.net? when you say bulk insert it sounds like a stored procedure execution.

Comment: Rogue, I never used that metod, I will search some info about it. Sebas, bulkinsert is the most close tag that I found, I have not enough reputation to create a new one. What I mean is that I have many rows in one insert. And yes, I have a BackgroundWorker doing the job.